# Feature: Down voting only shown with 2 or more down votes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I see how other people voted after I cast a vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22779/should-i-see-how-other-people-voted-after-i-cast-a-vote)

I have a suggestion, I know down-voting is used as a deterrent to bad answers and is completely subject to the down-voting user's opinion. If someone down votes an answer once, they appear to be penalized. I'm suggestion, now just spit-balling rather, that a down vote does not get shown or penalized until 2 or more users hit the down button. This would allow the community to make the right vote.

Now I don't know if this is a good idea in practice, so I'm only theorizing.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28737/limit-downvotes-visibility-to-3 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22779/should-i-see-how-other-people-voted-after-i-cast-a-vote http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70566/dont-show-negative-score-on-questions

Comment: It should be easier to locate these duplicates... I'm been visiting the pages it suggest when I enter my title.

Comment: Do the whole Digg thing. When I post a question, (after title and description) try to find like questions. Show me a dedicated screen that says are these questions like yours (all open in new windows) and if not then I'll go and post my question. This would stop my inability to find duplicates and me posting them.

Comment: @Justin Er, [seriously](http://so.mrozekma.com/meta-88500-related-questions.png)?

Comment: It would help considerable. Less duplicate questions, and its only one more page. I'm actually quite surprised that the process takes only one page. Or maybe just add content of the body to the Duplicate search box in the title. Make it easier to realize your question is similar to others. Because trying to do a search (outside of Google) for duplicates is quite difficult.

Comment: @Justin Did you [click the link](http://so.mrozekma.com/meta-88500-related-questions.png)? This exact thing already exists, except not on a separate page

Comment: Yes, but none of the good questions and answered should up for me. My point is all over those seemed to be lacking in many parts... sure they are similar. In any event, I'm not as happy as I'd like to be about the process but you are one of the top Q&A sites..! And I like that your growing.

Comment: Damn... I gotta say, @Justin... I like that you're trying to contribute here, but... You have *terrible* luck picking fresh topics. Please don't feel bad about this - you're bringing them up in new ways, and the auto-search function can only do so much... But... damn.